# laravel/beyondcode pusher not working with react-native returns an unavailable state

Tags: reactjs, laravel, react-native, websocket, pusher

```
const PusherClient = new Pusher('pusherAppKey001', {
    encrypted:true,
    wssPort:6001,
    wsHost:`${PUSHER_SERVER}`,
    cluster:'mt1',
    disableStats:true,
    authEndpoint: `${PUSHER_SERVER}/broadcasting/auth`,
    auth:{
      headers: { 
        Authorization: "Bearer " + jwtToken,
        Accept: "application/json"
    }
    },

});


PusherClient.connection.bind('state_change',(state)=>
{
  console.log(state);
   console.log(state.current);
})
```

If i use a key from pusher it works fine but according to beyondcode documentation we can set whatever app_id,key... want in our .env file and it will work just fine

Answer (score 0):

finally solved it after a couple hours of trying different things, turns out since i was working on my local machine i needed to set encrypted to false set transportation medium to ws and also change my default URL my current set up looks like this:

```
useEffect(() => {

    Pusher.logToConsole = true;

    let PusherClient = new Pusher('cf33f3r45fe34',{
        cluster: 'mt1',
        wsHost: PUSHER_SERVER,
        wsPort: '6001',
        encrypted:false,
        enabledTransports: ['ws'],
        forceTLS: false
    });

    let echo = new Echo({
        broadcaster: 'pusher',
        client: PusherClient
    });

    PusherClient.connection.bind('state_change',(data)=>
    {
      console.log('did it work?')
      console.log(data);
    })

    echo.channel('home').listen('NewMessage', (e) => {
        alert()
    });

})
```

note that my pusher server is my ip address without the http attached to it more like in this manner "192.168.33.12"